# Equivalence of Infinite Set Statements in ZFC

Tags: logic, set-theory

I was looking up ways to describe infinite sets in ZFC and came upon a curious problem. It involves proving the following equivalence using ZFC (i.e. the proof can't be colloquial).

For any set $A$,

$$
\text{There exists a surjective function }\ f : A \to \mathbb{N} \\
\iff \\\text{There is a strict subset $A' \subset A$ and surjective function } \ f' : A' \to A
$$

I'm stuck on both directions. For the forward direction I'm trying to use the right inverse from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$ to sort of index the elements of $A$ but no luck so far. Would appreciate any thoughts or ideas.

Comment: Also it would be nice to know the reason behind the close vote.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the axiom of choice lets you get left inverses to maps: a surjection from $X$ to $Y$ yields an injection from $Y$ to $X$. (The converse of course doesn't need choice.)

So your first property can be rewritten as

> (i) There is an injection $f$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$

and your second as

> (ii) There is some proper subset $A'\subset A$ and an injection $g$ from $A$ to $A'$.

These are going to be easier to work with.

For (i) implies (ii), remember that $\mathbb{N}$ is in bijection with lots of its proper subsets, and think about $A=f(\mathbb{N})\sqcup (A\setminus f(\mathbb{N}))$.

For (ii) implies (i), pick some $x\in A'\setminus A$, and think about the sequence $x, g(x), g(g(x)), ...$

---

Given the use of choice above, we might reasonably ask whether this problem *requires* the axiom of choice, or at least some amount of choice beyond ZF. The answer is yes!

It's consistent that we have disjoint sets $A_0, A_1, A_2, ...$ which are each infinite Dedekind-finite, and no one of which surjects onto another. Now let $A=\bigcup A_i$, and let $f$ send $a\in A_i$ to $i$. $A$ doesn't admit a surjection from any of its proper subsets.

Comment: I had a similar idea to what your hint for (i) seems to lead to. Roughly, I defined $A' = A - \{f(0)\}$ and defined the following injective function $g : A \to A'$. We have $g(x) = x$ if $x \in A - f(\mathbb{N})$ and $f(f^{-1}(x)^+) $ otherwise (such an inverse function exists since $f$ is injective). This is an injection from $A$ to $A'$ (I think) however I was hesitant with whether one can just define this piecewise function like this. Am I thinking about this the right way?